# Party model question

Tags: database-design

In the below Party Model diagram, why is there a COMMUNICATION EVENT WORK EFFORT entity, but no CASE WORK EFFORT derived from CASE entity? Should there be one single entity WORK EFFORT? Should it derive from COMMUNICATION EVENT or CASE entity or both? Is CASE required before WORK EFFORT?

[image: Party Model]